# Examples of bounded monotonic function

Tags: real-analysis

I want some examples of bounded monotone non decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Similarly  I would like to have example of bounded monotone non increasing function?

I know some basic examples like constant function but I am not able to find more. I know this is a very basic question. I will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classic example: the arctan function.
$$f(x) = \arctan (x)$$
[image]

If you want a non-increasing example, look at $f(x)=-\arctan(x)$.

Edit: You can also look at non-continuous functions like 
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0 \quad \text{if $x < 0$,} \\
1 \quad \text{if $x \geq 0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
$$
but these examples might be considered a bit pathological.

Answer (score 2):

More examples:
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{|x|+1} $$
$$g(x)=\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+1}} $$
and once you have one bounded monotonic function, you can just combine it with an arbitrary monotonic function, e.g.
$$ h(x)=f(e^{x^3}+17x)$$

Answer (score 1):

For non-decreasing $f(x)=1-\frac{1}{2^x+1}$

For non-increasing $f(x)=\frac{1}{2^x+1}$